# How to fill a series of columns given start and end dates in sql server table?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.

```
ProjectPlanTable
PPID
ProjectID
TaskID
StartDate
EndDate
NoofDays

ProjectDates
PDID
ProjectID
TaskID
D010101
D020101
D030201
D040101
D050101
D060101
D070101
D080101
D090101
D100101
..
..
D311201
```

(all 365 days in the year)

I want to update the D010101 with 'y' from the Project Plan table dates.

**For example:**
if ProjectA - TaskA - 010101 - 100101,

then in the ProjectDates table, D010101 to D100101 will be filled with 'y'.

How can I do this?

```
Project Plan Data
PPID  ProjectID   TaskID  StartDate   EndDate  Noof Days
1     ProjectA    Task1   010101      050101   5
2     ProjectA    Task2   030101      050101   3

The Project Data table shold look like below:
PDID  ProjectID  TaskID   D010101  D020101  D030101  D040101  D050101
1     ProjectA   Task1      y        y         y       y        y
2     ProjectA   Task2                         y       y        y
```

This is the query I used; but it is only updating the first task. I want every task to be updated.

```
UPDATE p
SET 
    D01012016 = CASE WHEN CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATE)   BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END,
    D02012016 = CASE WHEN CAST('2016-01-02' AS DATE ) BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END,
    D03012016 = CASE WHEN CAST('2016-01-03' AS DATE)   BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END,
    D04012016 = CASE WHEN CAST('2016-01-04' AS DATE ) BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END,
    D05012016 = CASE WHEN CAST('2016-01-05' AS DATE)   BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END,
    D06012016 = CASE WHEN CAST('2016-01-06' AS DATE ) BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END,
    D07012016 = CASE WHEN CAST('2016-01-07' AS DATE)   BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END,
    D08012016 = CASE WHEN CAST('2016-01-08' AS DATE ) BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END,
    D09012016 = CASE WHEN CAST('2016-01-09' AS DATE)   BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END,
    D10012016 = CASE WHEN CAST('2016-01-10' AS DATE ) BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END

FROM dbo.ProjectDates p 
INNER JOIN ProjectPlan pp ON p.Project = pp.Project AND p.Task = pp.Task
```

Comment: please add some test data,expected result.Current example is not clear..check here on how to ask and get help faster :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: thank u shiju.. how do I do this kind of formatting ?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting this will help u

Comment: Is the startdate & Enddates remains in the same month!?

Comment: No. Both Start and End Date can overflow to next month also.

Comment: Ok, need to write an SP. will share a basic version soon.

Comment: What is the Start Date & End date represents? DDMM??

Comment: DDMMYYYY. Project Date table columns also will be named as Dddmmyyyy for ex: D01012016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write UPDATE statement like this, you may need to tweak this as per your columns if it is varying every year.

```
DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(4) = '2016'

UPDATE p
SET 
    D010101 = CASE WHEN '0101' + @Year BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE '' END,
    D020101 = CASE WHEN '0201' + @Year BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE '' END,
    D030101 = CASE WHEN '0301' + @Year BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE '' END,
    D040101 = CASE WHEN '0401' + @Year BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE '' END,
    D050101 = CASE WHEN '0501' + @Year BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE '' END,
    D060101 = CASE WHEN '0601' + @Year BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE '' END,
    D070101 = CASE WHEN '0701' + @Year BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE '' END,
    D080101 = CASE WHEN '0801' + @Year BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE '' END,
    D090101 = CASE WHEN '0901' + @Year BETWEEN pp.StartDate AND pp.EndDate THEN 'y' ELSE '' END,
    -- and so on upto D311201
FROM Project p 
INNER JOIN ProjectPlan pp ON p.ProjectID = pp.ProjectID AND p.TaskID = pp.TaskID
```

Comment: simple.. however the 'int' can not be used. it fails with conversion error. so use actual date string like '01012016' etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a table with all Dates of the year (like DimDatum, which can be found in AdventureWorksDW) and performing some pivoting, such as:

```
DECLARE @StartDateKey int = 20120905;
DECLARE @EndDateKey int = 20120911;

WITH cte AS(
  SELECT 1 AS srt, 'D' + CAST(DateKey AS char(8)) AS DateKey, CASE WHEN DateKey >= @StartDateKey AND DateKey <= @EndDateKey THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END AS dummy
    FROM Tabelle
)
SELECT *
  FROM cte
  PIVOT (max(dummy) FOR DateKey IN ([D20120901], [D20120902], [D20120903], [D20120904], [D20120905], [D20120906],
                                    [D20120907], [D20120908], [D20120909], [D20120910], [D20120911], [D20120912],
                                    [D20120913], [D20120914], [D20120915], [D20120916], [D20120917], [D20120918],
                                    [D20120919], [D20120920], [D20120921], [D20120922], [D20120923], [D20120924])) AS pvt
```

With this done it should be easy to perform the corresponding Update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below SP,

This will automatically picks up the dates to be updated in `ProjectDates` table based on the start & end dates from `ProjectPlanTable` table.

```
CREATE Procedure UpdateProjectDates
as 
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @ProjectID varchar(50)
    DECLARE @TaskId varchar(50)
    DECLARE @StartDate varchar(50)
    DECLARE @EndDate varchar(50)
    DECLARE @NoofDays int
     DECLARE cur_ProjectPlanTable CURSOR
    STATIC FOR 
    SELECT  ProjectID, TaskId, SUBSTRING(StartDate,5,Len(StartDate)) +  SUBSTRING(StartDate,3,2) +  SUBSTRING(StartDate,1,2)  StartDate, SUBSTRING(EndDate,5,Len(EndDate)) +  SUBSTRING(EndDate,3,2) +  SUBSTRING(EndDate,1,2)   EndDate, NoofDays  
    From ProjectPlanTable
    OPEN cur_ProjectPlanTable
    IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0
    BEGIN 
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_ProjectPlanTable INTO @ProjectID,@TaskId, @StartDate, @EndDate, @NoofDays
        WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
            declare @Counter INT
            declare @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(1000)
            Set     @Counter=0
            Set @DynamicSQL = 'Update ProjectDates Set'

            DECLARE @T as table (RowNum INT, DateStr VARCHAR(10),UpdStatus INT)
            Delete From @T
            Insert Into @T
            SELECT  Nbr,RIGHT('0'+convert(varchar,Day(DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate))),2)+ RIGHT('0'+convert(varchar,Month(DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate))),2)+  convert(varchar(4), YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate)))   DateStr, 0 AS UpdStatus
            FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
                    FROM      sys.columns c
                    ) nbrs
            WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
            --Select * from @T
            DECLARE @RowCount INT
            SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM @T)
            DECLARE @I INT
            SET @I = 1

            WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
            BEGIN
                Set @DynamicSQL =@DynamicSQL+ ' D' + (Select DateStr + '= ''y'',' From @T Where RowNum = @I)
                SET @I = @I + 1
            END
            Set @DynamicSQL = SUBSTRING(@DynamicSQL,1,len(@DynamicSQL)-1) + ' Where ProjectId = ''' + Convert(Varchar,@ProjectId) + ''''  + ' and TaskId = ''' + Convert(Varchar,@TaskId) +''''
            PRINT @DynamicSQL 
             EXEC(@DynamicSQL)
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur_ProjectPlanTable INTO  @ProjectID,@TaskId, @StartDate, @EndDate, @NoofDays
         END
    END
    CLOSE cur_ProjectPlanTable
    DEALLOCATE cur_ProjectPlanTable
    SET NOCOUNT OFF 
end
```

Feel free to drop a message for further questions